# C# - ScheduledTasks class - how to specify localhost?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a problem with defining the local machine when trying to pull a list of Scheduled Tasks.

"localhost" doesn't seem to work, how could I define the current / local computer

```
private void testing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get a ScheduledTasks object for the computer named "DALLAS"
    ScheduledTasks st = new ScheduledTasks(@"localhost");

    // Get an array of all the task names
    string[] taskNames = st.GetTaskNames();

    // Open each task, write a descriptive string to the console
    foreach (string name in taskNames)
    {
        Task t = st.OpenTask(name);
        MessageBox.Show("  " + t.ToString());
        t.Close();
    }

    // Dispose the ScheduledTasks object to release COM resources.
    st.Dispose();  
}
```

Comment: FYI, what the OP is talking about: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation computer name needs to be a UNC name:

[ScheduledTasks Constructor (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb507587%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Therefore, the following should work:

```
string machineName = (@"\\" + System.Environment.MachineName);

ScheduledTasks st = new ScheduledTasks(machineName);
```

Comment: @chibacity Thanks, but it throws an exception, saying the network path is not found :/

Comment: @dennis: Fire up your debugger. What does reflection tell you about .MachineName?

Comment: @Dennis Strange. One issue I can see from the documentation is that you need admin privileges to access the task information. Do you have admin rights on the machine?

Comment: @0A0D The path is not valid on my local machine anyway, I am not on a corporate network

Comment: @chibacity Hi, yes I have a modified manifest as appropriate and the application is running with administrative rights

Comment: @dennis It shouldn't matter if you're not on a domain, as MachineName returns the Netbios name for the machine which you'll have whether you're on a domain or not. Out of interest do you get the same issue with @"\\localhost"?

Comment: @Dennis: Lets' try this again.. what does .MachineName return? Is it the name of your machine? Have you tried removing the double backslashes?

Comment: @chibacity Netbios is completely disabled on my machine, for security issues. I can only assume this is the reason behind it? Using \\localhost gives same reuslt

Comment: @Dennis: The name is obtained from the registry at computer startup. The user you are running as may not have access to this information thus you would get an InvalidOperationException.

Comment: ************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The network path was not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070035)
   at TaskSchedulerInterop.ITaskScheduler.SetTargetComputer(String Computer)
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.testing_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\app\Form1.cs:line 675
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)

Comment: @0A0D Using @"\\127.0.0.1" locks up the application for about 20 seconds, it then tries to access my DNS servers and then throws and exception

Comment: @Dennis: It's obvious you have a operating system configuration problem that is not fixable by code.

Comment: @0A0D As stated earlier its proberly becuase OS has been heavily tweaked, netbios disabled etc, but yeh, something is pretty f**** up

Comment: @dennis Something very strange is going on if something is trying to access DNS, as that is an IP address - no DNS should be required for @"\\127.0.0.1".

Answer (score 0):

try to use `Environment.MachineName`

```
ScheduledTasks st = new ScheduledTasks(Environment.MachineName);
```